# Cisco router access list not working as expected

Tags: cisco, routing, acl, access-control

I'm trying to set up a network in packet tracer with inter-VLAN routing. I need to restrict one of the VLANs to only accept traffic from the 172.25.30.0/24 network.

To do this I am using an access list:

```
access-list 1 permit 172.25.30.0 0.0.0.255
```

I have 5 subinterfaces for the different VLANs on the network, and have applied the access list to f0/0.50:

```
interface FastEthernet0/0.10
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 ip address 172.25.10.254 255.255.255.0
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.20
 encapsulation dot1Q 20
 ip address 172.25.20.254 255.255.255.0
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.30
 encapsulation dot1Q 30
 ip address 172.25.30.254 255.255.255.0
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.40
 encapsulation dot1Q 40
 ip address 172.25.40.254 255.255.255.0
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.50
 encapsulation dot1Q 50
 ip address 172.25.50.254 255.255.255.0
 ip access-group 1 in
!
```

As far as I can tell this should now only allow devices on the 172.25.30.0/24 network to communicate with devices on the 172.25.50.0/24 network (my management network). However, as soon as I apply the access list to the sub-interface I can no longer ping the 172.25.50.0/24 network from any devices, including ones on the 172.25.30.0/24 network.

Can anyone see why this would be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the direction of the ACL to `out`.

```
ip access-group 1 out
```

The direction is from the perspective of the router interface. `Out` means out of the interface, towards the devices.